# How to build my back end server in android?

Tags: android, authentication, server

Can someone please give me an idea on how to setup my server side. I have an app that logins via user account but I have no idea about server side. I, now want to connect my app to the server. What is the best idea?

Can anypne please give me some reference or simple example about this?
Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: better to search on _Google_

Comment: one way to do this is to build a `RESTful API` this can be achieved in several languages such as Java, Vb, C#, ... so try to find how to build it with your favorite language

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too broad to get an answer here. You better search for some tutorial

Comment: A multi-tier application first needs to be defined in terms of functionalities, then you define the flow and content of communication. After that you write the server program, which has nothing to do with android per se and connect it with your app using one of the many available connection types that have their advantages and disadvantages based on use case.

Comment: if you know some reference regarding this, please share it.

Comment: I don't why you all are down voting me. All I want here is some references or example but no one is giving my answer here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do, however the cheapest and most popular method is using a PHP server. Then you would be using Volley to call the database and parse the data onto your app. Obviously your app would have a totally new functionality to write data and read it to and and from a database. Your app doesn't remain an offline boring one, but it will have the functionality to become a dynamic one.

The best tutorial I found when implement such a project was [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/).

Comment: Thank you. I think it will help a lot.